# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : using jsonp callback

Tags: ajax, jsonp

I am making a cross browser jsonp call in which my backend to which i am sending some values is made using `django` and getting some after callback to my front end which is in php . The problem is its giving `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` error The data is being send from the django and i have checked that. i am using the code below to make jsonp calls

```
$(document).on('click', '.miloginme', function(event) {

        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var token = $('#token').val();
var dataString="uid="+username+"&token="+token;     

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "http://localhost:8000/b/authenticate/",
crossDomain: true,
data: dataString,
async: false,
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
}); 


});
```

the values in callback that i am getting is in format

```
{"token": "KAMWMS151UWPR4Q", "authenticate": "1", "userid": "brad", "fname": "rahul", "booster_number": "1"}
```

Answer (score 3):

*tldr;* The server is not sending back [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Value reported in the post is JSON (and it is valid JSON) - it is *not* JSONP. If it were to be treated as JSONP (i.e. evaluated by a `<script>`) then it would be a syntax error because it is *not* a valid JavaScript program.

Try this in a JavaScript console:

> {"token": "KAMWMS151UWPR4Q", "authenticate": "1", "userid": "brad", "fname": "rahul", "booster_number": "1"}

Error look familiar? (Different browses can return different error messages: Chrome -> "Unexpected token :", FireFox -> "invalid label", IE9 -> "Expected ';'".)

A valid JSONP result would look similar to:

> theCallback({"token": "KAMWMS151UWPR4Q", "authenticate": "1", "userid": "brad", "fname": "rahul", "booster_number": "1"})

(The name of `theCallback` is taken from the `jsonp` variable passed to the server and the client - e.g. jQuery - creates this function before the [injecting `<script>` element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Script_element_injection) is created so that the function can be invoked using the above syntax.)

*Valid* JSONP works because the "JSON" data is then run in an expression context (in which it is treated as a valid JavaScript Object Literal), not a statement context (where it is treated as a label and then "some junk" leading to a syntax error).

Common approaches to return JSONP from Django utilize [View Decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/):

- [Django JSONP Decorator](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2208/)
- [Returning JSON/JSONP from a Django view with a little decorator help](https://coderwall.com/p/k8vb_a)
- [jsonp_decorator.py](https://gist.github.com/sivy/871954)

Comment: i used return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data_inner), mimetype="application/json") in django is this casuing issue?

Comment: @user1001176 That is indeed incorrect as it returns JSON, but *not* JSONP. I've added more details and relevant links.

Comment: just saved me some pain, couldn't figure out why a test URL was working, and my live data wasn't. Thanks @user2246674 :)